# Django Server: python manage.py runserver - Not Found: /url/

Tags: django

I am a newbie when it comes to Django and am getting stuck on what seems a very basic issue.

When I create a new Django project in the conda prompt and then start the django server, it always seems to try redirect to a url that doesn't exist.

Steps taken in conda prompt:

```
django-admin startproject mysite

cd mysite

python manage.py runserver
```

This will start the server with the usual http://127.0.0.1:8000/ local site however when loading this up in my chrome browser it always redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/

I see in the conda prompt that Not Found: /blog/ is shown

### [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj6Hl.png) ##

I haven't changed any code in the project, so the urls.py haven't set a redirect in the url pattern or anything like that.

How do I stop this redirect from happening?

Note: if I do the following

```
python manage.py runserver 7000
```

to change the port this redirect doesn't happen, but I am trying to solve for why its happening on 8000.

Comment: Did you previously have some server running on the same address that established a *permanent redirect* which the browser is remembering? Try clearing caches… Debug in more detail by using another browser or `curl` to get the raw response from just `/`.

Comment: please post your urls.py

Comment: @FarhaniWalid the urls.py is exactly as it would be on starting the project, so it would be the urlpatterns = path('admin/', admin.site.urls)

Comment: @deceze yeah - that seems to be it - really simple!! Told you I was a newb

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear - the http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ site was cached from a previous project, so whenever I tried to load up http://127.0.0.1:8000 it would load the /blog/ url.

Solution = Clear the cache on your browser

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked Nginx / Apache proxy server configs, I think You are running some proxy server and redirecting to /blog for 8000 port.

Comment: If another server was running on the same port, the Django server wouldn't be able to bind to it.